# Architecture of android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm bit confused about architecture of android wear device. Actually I'm researching on it to find out how application works and interacts with the handheld device.

I know that its a complete OS , another version of android. I very well know about the architecture of android. But its a watch now, having smaller memories, smaller processor minus a lot of hardware etc. So should I suppose that the Android Wear architecture is same as the architecture of android minus the blocks which are not present in an android wear device?

Like for android handheld devices we have first layer of linux which has hardware drivers(wi-fi, bluetooth, camera, display etc.). Above this layer are libraries and android runtime. Above that we have frameworks and at the last we have actual applications through which end user interacts.

Comment: The big difference is the Activity. In Android Wear the Activity has a different set of events and methods which are plugged into the OS to understand when: 1) Time is changed 2) A notification is delivered 3) luminosity of the screen is changed and so on.
The AOSP is the same, the major differences are in the power management, the kernel and the home screen